# Excel Date formatting from Text string

Tags: excel, string, date

I have the following date formatted as text, which is retrieved from an external source, e.g.

> September 9, 2017 12:05 PM BST

I need to convert these text strings to a date format that I can use in calculations, but for the life of me I can get this to work using `DateValue`, `Value`, text to columns etc...

Would prefer to do this via functions rather than programmatically - any assistance appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Remove the timezone indicator.  That is non-standard so Excel cannot recognize the string as a date.

Answer (score 0):

=TEXT(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)+5),"dd-mmm-yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula,

```
=DATE(YEAR(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"BST",""),"mm/dd/yyyy")),MONTH(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"BST",""),"mm/dd/yyyy")),DAY(TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"BST",""),"mm/dd/yyyy")))
```

[image]

You can use the result in calculations.

Comment: Hi This didn't work for me - when I ran the calculation it returns a #value error

Comment: Split the Year, month, day formulas and try it individually. If you still get error, post the image. wanted to see how you use the formula and how you have the data

Comment: Got it working using Text to Columns in the end - thanks for the help

Comment: @user8171169 Thats great